# jQuery page up and down scroll based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, event-handling

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    });
    $("#maincontainer").mousemove(function() {
        // $('#DivToShow').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
        $('#DivToShow').html("Y " + mouseY + " --- " + "X " + mouseX);
        if (mouseY > 230) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollBottom: $elem.height()
            }, 800);
        }
    });
});
```

pls help, I am trying to make a auto page up and down scroll based on pointer position. when pointer coming to bottom of browser, page need to scroll down 60px ++. not a single scroll to end of page.

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle` demo of your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/Lj4mekos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

On mousemove, get the clientY and the window height. If the difference is less than 60, then scroll 60 more than the current scrollTop:

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var y = e.clientY;
  var h = $(window).height();
  var n = h - y;  
  if (n < 60) {
    var t = parseFloat($(window).scrollTop());
    console.log(t);
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:t + 60 + 'px'},200);
  } else {
    $('html,body').stop();
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper,
.section {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

.section { 
  height:80px;
  border:1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. this is aimed logic. but need opposite direction (to top) also. 200 used for what purpose, what is this value for ?

Comment: 200 indicates the animation speed in milliseconds (200 = 0.2sec / 1000 = 1 sec)

Comment: Use if (y < 60) instead of if (n < 60)

Comment: what is the use of console.log(t)

Comment: Just for testing reasons

Comment: Is it possible to make this scrolling continuously & very slightly when 'n' reach < 25? if n < 60 & >25  need same effect as per current code.

Comment: Pls help, how to make this scroll continuously & slowly if I keep mouse Y pos below 60 ?